# Jetpack Compose Breaking GSON

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-jetpack-compose

I have an working Android project whenever I add **Jetpack Compose Dependencies** my **GSON** is not working as expected. The Strange things if I remove **excludeFieldsWithModifiers** or if I don't use any **inheritance** for the classes which I am parsing using GSON then it's working.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Add **Jetpack Compose Runtime** or **Jetpack Compose Dependencies**
2. Add **GSON** Dependencies
3. Use **GsonBuilder** to create **GSON** Object and add **excludeFieldsWithModifiers** option
4. Create a simple class hierarchy
5. Try to parse any json using to **Child class** which you have created above using the same **GSON** Object (Created in **Step 3**)

For Illustration purpose I am adding one sample

```
class Response(@SerializedName("id") var id : Int = 0) : BaseResponse()
open class BaseResponse

val gsonMapper: Gson by lazy {
GsonBuilder()
    .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(
        java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT. // Can you any other modifier
    )
    .create()
}

fun responseProcess() {
  try {
      val response = """{"id": 3}"""
      val data = gsonMapper.fromJson(response, Response::class.java)
      Log.d(TAG, "responseProcess: $data")
  } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

StackTrace for the above Code

```
2022-11-30 18:14:12.162 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.bhaskar.myapplication.Response declares multiple JSON fields named $stable
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:926)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.bhaskar.myapplication.MainActivityKt.responseProcess(MainActivity.kt:74)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.bhaskar.myapplication.MainActivityKt$Greeting$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:54)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.bhaskar.myapplication.MainActivityKt$Greeting$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:53)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:153)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:142)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:223)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.163 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:511)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:406)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:419)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:310)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:179)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:98)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:80)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1159)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1109)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1059)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3920)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3594)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3920)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3594)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3920)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3594)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3920)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3594)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:915)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1957)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4182)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.164 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:873)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:15458)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7457)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7233)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6595)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6786)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6843)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6618)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6626)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9880)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9718)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9671)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10014)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.165 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.166 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.166 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.166 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.166 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.166 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    2022-11-30 18:14:12.166 14856-14856/com.bhaskar.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `excludeFieldsWithModifiers` you overwrite the default modifier exclusions. Therefore now you (accidentally?) include `static` fields, and `$stable` seems to be a synthetic field [added by the compiler](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/internal/StabilityInferred) (not sure though why Gson is not detecting that it is synthetic).

You can solve this by adding `Modifier.STATIC` to the modifiers as well:

```kotlin
excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT or Modifier.STATIC)
```

(though note that this is effectively the same as the default Gson field exclusion)

If you need to serialize `static` fields for some reason, then you might have to write a custom [`ExclusionStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html) to ignore the unwanted `$stable` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have couple of confusion, 1. Why Compose compiler adding that field to my class when I am not even using the class in any of the compose function? 2. What is mean by **stability is inferred** (from the doc); what exactly mean by **stability**?

Comment: @Bhaskar, sorry I am actually not that familiar with Android development and only assumed that this `StabilityInferred` annotation is the cause for the `$stable` field (I might be wrong though). Might be best to search if there is more information about this annotation and the field, and if not just ask a separate question about it.